# Notificações Moodle

Tags: moodle

Alguém sabe como faço para modificar as notificações que são enviadas através do forum do moodle?
Ex:
Quando criar um tópico, quero que um e-mail seja enviado com uma mensagem para o instrutor, e para o aluno outra mensagem.

Comment: Verifique o método de inscrição, caso necessário acesse o menu de administração do moodle para executar a alteração.